# How to trigger window.onbeforeunload in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Currently, I have created a directive attached to a form. Anytime the form is dirty, I have a confirmation modal by window.onbeforeunload pop up when trying to leave. Right now I'm trying to write a jasmine test to make sure window.onbeforeunload gets called upon refresh/url change.

```
var app = angular.directive('app');

app.directive('dialog',[$window, function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
            $window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if(formCtrl.$dirty) {
                    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this form';
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Part of the Jasmine Spec

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$state_,_$window_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $state = _$state_;
    $window = _$window_;

    spyOn($window, 'onbeforeunload')
}));

describe('Listen for window prompt', function () {
    it('should be called on url/refresh change', function () {
        window.location.reload();
        expect($window.onbeforeunload).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to test if the method does what it is supposed to do which is fire when the url has changed/refreshed. You should probably be testing the code that happens inside this event. You can trigger this event in your jasmine script by using the jquery trigger command on the window object:

```js
$(window).trigger('onbeforeunload');
```

Comment: When I did fire the onbeforeunload event, it would break the jasmine tests and do a complete refresh on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

In a unit test it's enough just to test your implementation of the 'onbeforeunload' event. Otherwise you can write e2e test with [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/).

You can do your test like this:

```
describe('page leave handler', function () {
  it('should handle page leave', function () {
    // given
    var element = compileDirective();
    var formCtrl = element.controller('ngForm');
    formCtrl.$dirty = true;

    // when
    var result = $window.onbeforeunload();

    // then
    expect(result).toBe('Are you sure..');
  });
});
```

Comment: I got TypeError: window.onbeforeunload is not a function